# How to debug push notification while app is not launched?

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I want to deal with a remote push notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method while my app was not launched(i killed them after launched),how can i debug this situation?

Comment: What do you want to debug?

Comment: No other way then you print logs and check the console of device or else you can pop up alert where you want to debug.

Answer (score 13):

You can acheive this in this way:

In your Project's target select Edit Scheme and then change this setting:

Change **Automatically** to **wait for executable to be launched**.

Keep your device connected and run the app. It will debug when you will send notification.

[image]