# When I click FCM push notification, I want to run my app. (in swift4)

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showSplashScreen") as? ShowSplashScreen {
        if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
            var currentController = rootViewController
            while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                currentController = presentedController
            }
            currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } 
}
```

Once the app is running, when I click fcm push notification, it opens well. But when I quit my app in background, and I click fcm push notification it doesn't work. It seems like app is being killed. 
What should I do if I want to run my app when I click the fcm notification? (when app is not running)

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and tried debugging what happens when the app control comes here?

Comment: I want to, but what should I do if I want to see action when app is killed?
What I want to do is killed my app, receive push notification, click the notification and app is running.

Comment: To detect if the opened from a push notification, set a breakpoint in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate, and look for UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification in the launch options. You can start debugging from there.

Comment: But what I want to do is to debug situation after I click push notification.

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855246/how-to-debug-push-notification-while-app-is-not-launched

Comment: @KunalShah Thank u Sooooo much!!! :)

Comment: Please upvote my comments if it helped you out!